# How to compile c complex numbers with c++11

Tags: c++11, complex-numbers

I am extending a project which compiles some libraries with c99 and one library with c++11 and uses complex.h complex numbers in the c99 library.

I know this may be a stupid idea but it wasn't mine and I need to make it work somehow.

The code does not compile with gcc4.9 and -std=c++11 and I am quite clueless what to do. How do I make this snippet compile?

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  double _Complex a = 3.0 + 0.0 * _Complex_I;
  //printf("%lf\n", creal(a));
  return 0;
}
```

Gives the error

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/complex.h:36:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:5:33: error: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""iF'
   double _Complex a = 3.0 + 0.0 _Complex_I;
                                 ^
main.cpp:5:33: note: use -std=gnu++11 or -fext-numeric-literals to enable more built-in suffixes
main.cpp:5:33: error: expression cannot be used as a function
   double _Complex a = 3.0 + 0.0 _Complex_I;
                                 ^
main.cpp:5:19: warning: unused variable 'a' [-Wunused-variable]
   double _Complex a = 3.0 + 0.0 _Complex_I;
```

with

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
```

-std=gnu++11 works it seems, but is there a way to make it work with -std=c++11?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `double complex a = 3.0 + 0.0 * _Complex_I;`? (Note the `*`)

Comment: right. I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to compile c complex numbers with c++11

You don't. Standard C++ does not support the `<complex.h>` C library header.

Either:

- Use the GCC language extensions.
- Implement a wrapper function for anything that deals with C complex numbers that provides an interface which doesn't use C complex numbers. Implement the wrapper in C and use the wrapper from C++.
- Don't use C complex numbers in the first place - use `std::complex` instead.

Comment: This is really sad. Will -std=gnu++11 compile on Windows by any chance? Thanks for the options!

Comment: @Philipp You could try the Minimalist GNU for Windows.

Comment: Thanks, mingw seems to support -std=gnu++11